# I am trying to check document type but getting error Refused to get unsafe header "Accept-Ranges"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the code below, I am trying to check the document file, but it gives me

> error: Refused to get unsafe header "Accept-Ranges"

```
if (docs.Answers != "" && docs.Answers != null) {
        var parts = docs.Answers.split('/');
        var answer = parts[parts.length - 1];
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/" + answer + "/metadata",
            headers: {
                Authorization: undefined
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data.mimetype != "application/pdf") {
                $scope.interviewSummary.Documents.Answers = "https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:pdf/" + $scope.interviewSummary.Documents.Answers
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
    /*});*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow Ranges using Headers :

Put HTTP Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept-Ranges, Content-Encoding, Content-Length, Content-Range
```